# Remove library dependency

Tags: c++, boost, linker, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have some boost-dependent code I want to compile as a dynamic library:

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -o myclass.o -c myclass.cpp 
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,myclass.so.1 -o lib/myclass.so.1 myclass.o -lc
```

However after compiling I notice there is still a boost dependency (I'm checking with `ldd`)

```
ldd lib/myclass.so.1
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff741fd000)
libboost_system.so.1.60.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.60.0 (0x00007f7945649000)
libboost_serialization.so.1.60.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.60.0 (0x00007f794540b000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7945089000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7944d83000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f79449e2000)
/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005590726ae000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f79447cc000)
librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f79445c3000)
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f79443a6000)
```

Is there any way to remove boost dynamic dependency on my shared library (pack the current boost version of the objects I'm calling in the .so)?

Comment: Did you try `ldd -v` to check whether any the libraries it links against links to Boost?

Answer (score 0):

> `g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,myclass.so.1 -o lib/myclass.so.1 myclass.o -lc`
>
> However after compiling I notice there is still a boost dependency

You mean "after linking".

There is *no way* for the link command you gave to produce a library that depends on boost, unless your `g++` is actually an alias for something else.

If it is an alias, don't use it. If you have a hacked-up `g++` or if you modified its `specs` file, don't do that.

If the command you gave is not the *actual* command you used, show us the actual command (and remove boost from it).

Comment: I used that command specifically thorugh a makefile, and ran `ldd` on the .so file generated. Both the library itself and binaries linked to it show boost dependencies.